# The contraction of an ideal in a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f:R\rightarrow{S}$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. The extension $I^e=f(I)S$. Let $A$ be an ideal in $S$. The contraction $A^c=f^{-1}(A)$ is always an ideal in $R$.

But I have read that if $D$ is a subring of a ring $E$ and $J$ is an ideal in $E$ then the contaction of $J$ is $J^c=J\cap{D}$. I am looking whether there is any connection between these two definitions. Can we say that for the ideal $A$ in $S$, the contraction $A^c=f^{-1}(A)=A\cap{R}$?

Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The homomorphism, in the case of a subring, is the inclusion map.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your answer. Let $f:D\rightarrow{E}$ be the inclusion map, D a subring of $E$. Let $J$ be an ideal in $E$. Why $f^{-1}(J)=J\cap{D}$?

Comment: Prove it yourself, it's easy.

Comment: Is this right? If $J$ is an ideal in $E$, then $f^{-1}(J)$ is the set of $x\in{D}$ such that $f(x)\in{J}$, that is, the set $x\in{D}$ such that $x\in{J}$, which is equal to $J\cap{D}$.

Comment: That's right $\space$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case $D$ is a subring of $E$, then the homomorphism under consideration is the inclusion map $i\colon D\to E$, $i(x)=x$.

If $J$ is an ideal of $E$, then
$$
J^c=\{x\in D:i(x)\in J\}=D\cap J
$$
by definition of intersection.