# Ideals in $R$ and $R[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, polynomial-rings

A simple fact with a simple proof, both of which I wished to see in one place:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit, and let

$I \subset R[x] \tag 1$

be an ideal in $R[x]$.  Prove that

$I \cap R \subset R \tag 2$

is an ideal in $R$.

***Note Added in Edit, Tuesday 12 May 2020 5:24 PM PST:***  This note is written in response to the comments on the questiion made by Gone, in which he points out that the result here may be very naturally extended to the case where $R$ is a subring of some arbitrary unital commutative ring $E$,

$R \subset E, \tag 3$

where we do not necessarily have

$E = R[x]; \tag 4$

Gone points out that if we replace $R[x]$ with $E$, and assume

$I \subset E \tag 5$

is an ideal, then the proof given in the answer goes through unchanged, yielding a noteworthy generalization to the result as stated by Yours Truly in the above formulation of this problem.  To wit, following Gone's suggestion we show that if $R$ is a subring of any ring $E$, $I \cap R$ is an ideal of $R$. ***End of Note.***

Comment: I generalized it to any ring extension.  Writing everything in displaystyle may serve to emphasize little things that don't deserve such emphasis, e.g. the proof is easier to grasp when written in a few lines.

Comment: @Gone:  I used displaystyle because I find it easier to read.  I had very specific reasons for stating the question the way I did.

Comment: The  proof has nothing to do with $R[x]$ other than it being a suppering of $R$. So why do you wish to obfuscate the generality of the result by needlessly restricting it this way?

Comment: @Gone:  Beacuse I needed to say it this way to refer to it in another piece I am writing.  From my point of view, the generality obfuscates.  Look, I really don't want to get into an argument about this, but why don't you ask the question you want it to be for yourself?  Wouldn't that serve your ends?

Comment: This is not a good idea since it may confuse readers to wrongly believe that it only holds in this special case. Notice that your argument makes no use of $R[x]$ other than it being a commutative ring (with $1$) containing $R$. The only thing you need to change is to replace $R[x]$ by $E$. It introduces no extra complexity (in fact it simplifies matters).

Comment: fyi: this is a special case of ideal contraction (along a ring hom), e.g. see Atiyah & Macdonald p.9 on ideal extension and contraction. We already have answers on this special case, e.g.[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407071/242) and likely many others.

Comment: @Gone:  I am preparing some edits to my question in order to address your concerns. Hang tight.  Should be done pretty soon.  Cheers!

Comment: @Gone:  OK, I added a note to my question.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$I \cap R \ne \emptyset, \tag 0$

since

$0 \in I \cap R. \tag{0.5}$

Now if

$r_1, r_2 \in I \cap R, \tag 1$

then since

$r_1, r_2 \in I, \tag 2$

an ideal, we have

$r_1 - r_2 \in I; \tag 3$

since

$r_1, r_2 \in R, \tag 4$

a ring,

$r_1 - r_2 \in R; \tag 5$

thus

$r_1 - r_2 \in I \cap R; \tag 6$

with

$s \in I \cap R \tag 7$

and

$r \in R, \tag 8$

we also have

$rs \in I, \tag 9$

again since $I$ is an ideal; furthermore,

$rs \in R, \tag{10}$

since $R$ is a ring; thus,

$rs \in I \cap R, \tag{11}$

and we conclude that $I \cap R$ is an ideal in $R$.

Comment: Might want to note that $I\cap R$ is not empty, too...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  I will take note of that and edit accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  I will attend to your concerns as soon as I finish addressing those of Gone, stated in comments to the question itself.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  I will get back to these edits as soon as I finish addressing the concerns of user Gone, stated in comments to the question itself.  Cheers!